# Manticore. Индекс создан, но при запросе его нет

Tags: sphinx

Установил сервер с таким конфигом в docker-compose.yml

```
manticore:
    container_name: manticore
    image: manticoresearch/manticore
    restart: always
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
         soft: 65535
         hard: 65535
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - ./manticore/data:/var/lib/manticore
      - ./manticore/data/manticore.conf:/etc/manticoresearch/manticore.conf
    restart: always
    environment:
      MANTICORE_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
```

Затем проиндексировал

```
root@5681a6aade90:/var/lib/manticore# indexer --all --rotate
Manticore 5.0.2 348514c86@220530 dev
Copyright (c) 2001-2016, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
Copyright (c) 2017-2022, Manticore Software LTD (https://manticoresearch.com)

using config file '/etc/manticoresearch/manticore.conf'...
indexing index 'idx_sections_pubs'...
collected 27 docs, 0.0 MB
creating lookup: 0.0 Kdocs, 100.0% done
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 27 docs, 5693 bytes
total 0.602 sec, 9456 bytes/sec, 44.84 docs/sec
indexing index 'idx_mfc_services'...
collected 1097 docs, 0.2 MB
creating lookup: 1.0 Kdocs, 100.0% done
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 1097 docs, 296435 bytes
total 0.307 sec, 965077 bytes/sec, 3571.40 docs/sec
total 6 reads, 0.000 sec, 23.7 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 35 writes, 0.001 sec, 21.2 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: successfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=1).
```

Затем попробовал сделать запрос

```
root@5681a6aade90:/var/lib/manticore# mysql
mysql> select count(*) from idx_sections_pubs where match('bla');
ERROR 1064 (42000): unknown local index(es) 'idx_sections_pubs' in search request
```

Локально при одинаковых конфигах (только пароли разные) все работает

На тестовом сервере тоже работает

На проде - нет.

Куда копать? что можно сделать? как понять?

UPD1.

Грохнул все, поправил конфиг (предположил что source у idx_sections_pubs слишком длинный) снова проиндексировал и теперь `show tables` показывает только `idx_sections_pubs`...

Вот файлики что были созданы. Почему-то часть из них созданы из под `root`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD2.

Странные вещи. После `docker-compose restart manticore` уже у других файлов стал владелец `root` и `show tables;` теперь показывает только `idx_mfc_services`. Я в шоках. Причем и сами права меняются, не только владелец. Мжб я запускаю indexer не от того пользователя? хотя я только restart контейнера делаю...

UPD3.

При создании индекса командой с явным указанием пользователя все файлы создаются с нужными правами, но в mysql мантикоры нет таблиц, пока не перезагрузишь контейнер (мжб можно обойтись без перезагрузки?)

```
docker-compose exec manticore gosu manticore indexer --all --rotate
```

Когда перезагружаешь контейнер - права снова слетают (владелец и атрибуты у некоторых файлов)

UPD4

Пробовал в docker-compose.yml указать параметр `user` с пользователем, который индексы использует внутри контейнера (999), но он не может создать pid файл, нет прав

UPD5

Посмотрел права на подмонтированную папку data и конфиг файл внутри на тестовом сервере, где все работает. Отличался владелец (на тесте root, на проде user), группа одна и та же (systemd-coredump) и еще атрибуты у папки и конфиг файла сделал так же. не помогло

Также проверил меняются ли права у файлов на тесте после рестарта. Не меняются

Comment: `show tables;` показывает что-нибудь интересное?

Comment: @andreymal, там только idx_mfc_services, idx_services_pubs нет... и ошибок при команде indexer нет... оч странно. В папке с файлами есть файлы как mfc_services.spa, mfc_services.spb и тд, и также есть sections_pubs.spa, sections_pubs.spb и тд. И есть еще sections_pubs.new.spa и тд.

Comment: Проблема окружения . Смотрите журнал, на проде должна быть строчка `indexing index 'idx_sections_pubs'...`. Если ее нет - почему команда не запускается.

Comment: @TotalPusher, вот в задаче я лог вывел, там есть эта строка

Comment: Да, запускать нужно не от рута. `docker exec -it manticore gosu manticore indexer --all --rotate` - из [официальной документации](https://hub.docker.com/r/manticoresearch/manticore). Есть от рута, файлы индексов также принадлежат пользователю root, и сервис не может прочитать такие файлы, он работает от имени manticore, uid 999. У вас показывается как systemd-coredump, потому что смотрите не в контейнере, а на хосте. uid 999 на хосте соответствует systemd-coredump

Comment: @TotalPusher, снес индексы, перезапустил, проиндексировал как вы написали - все файлики от одного пользователя и с нужными атрибутами. `show tables;` показал пустоту. Перезапустил контейнер. Снова побились права на файлы и авторы. То есть это происходит в момент перезапуска контейнера. Что тут можно сделать с правами?